# Slowing Down Testimonials carousel

Tags: wordpress, testimonials

H! I am working with a wordpress theme that hast testimonials.

I am trying to slow down the testimonials. The theme strangely doesn't offer any help with this. What would I need to do to slow it down? This is the [Div Site](http://div.morganrhea.cyndeeadkinsdesign.com/).

I'm trying to figure out what defines it's speed, and then where to go to slow it down.

The theme being used is called Stockholm. And in their documentation they don't give the ability to slow down the time you have to read the testimonial. It only allows you to slow down the speed of the transition itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to slow down the Testimonials in Stockholm is to go to “Classic Mode” and change the speed of the slider in the shortcode.

You would look for this in the shortcode: `auto_rotate_slides="8" animation_type="fade" animation_speed="3000"`